# Eclipse toolbar with multiple rows

Tags: eclipse, toolbar, rcp

In my RCP app, I contribute several items to the main toolbar. The easy question now is: How do I make Eclipse lay them out so that they appear in a second row, just under the normal toolbar? Or can I add an additional toolbar that appears just under the main bar? Right now, they just appear somewhere between the other items contributed by other plugins. I tried a lot of stuff and searched a long time, couldn't find any answer though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid the main eclipse toolbar is beyond programatic control, it is entirely up to the user how he arranges the items. I've tried similar to arrange perspective buttons with no success.